# Save data while entering background - ResearchKit

Tags: ios, swift, researchkit

I am developing an application in swift using research kit framework. When TaskViewController is loaded to display the questionnaire on click of cancel or done the following function is called:

```
func taskViewController(taskViewController: ORKTaskViewController, 
                     didFinishWithReason reason: ORKTaskViewControllerFinishReason, 
                     error: NSError?)
```

Could anyone please help me to understand how to save the data each time when the application enters background. I tried calling didFinishWithReason function manually, but it didn't work.

Comment: Resolved. I just needed to make global object of the task view controller. And on entering background, if that object.result is accessed, the results can be fetched . :)

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. I just needed to make global object of the task view controller. And on entering background, if that object.result is accessed, the results can be fetched . :)